Fit text to richTextBox
I am looking for some solution to fit the text into the frame. I don't expect the frame to be round. I just need to allow users to enter text inside it.
Program trying to write in c# with .net forms.
The problem is that I don't know what to use, because I checked richTextBox with multiline and wordwrap, but the formatting at some stage becomes scrollable, which I don't want. The text should only fit within that graphics.
What I have got:

What I need:

I would like the text to fit only in the size of the given format without scroll.
simply i've tried with RichTextBox, but user stil can put some enter in half of line which in result sends a lot of text to line where text is cutted.
       
public class CustomTextBox : RichTextBox
{
    public CustomTextBox()
    { 
        Location = new Point(54, 50);
        Multiline = true;
        WordWrap = true;
        Size = new Size(600, 120);
        Dock = DockStyle.None;
        BorderStyle = BorderStyle.None;
        ScrollBars = RichTextBoxScrollBars.None;
        ForeColor = Color.Black;
        BackColor = Color.Yellow;
    }
}
private void InitializeForm()
{
    CustomTextBox customBox = new CustomTextBox()
    customBox.TextChanged += CustomBox_TextChanged;
    this.Controls.Add(customBox)
}

private void CustomBox_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    RichTextBox rtb = sender as RichTextBox;
    
    int lastCharIndex = rtb.TextLength - 1;
    if (lastCharIndex <0)
    {
        return;
    }

    Point lastCharPosition = rtb.GetPositionFromCharIndex(lastCharIndex);
    if (lastCharPosition.Y + rtb.Font.Height >= rtb.ClientSize.Height && lastCharPosition.X + rtb.Font.SizeInPoints >= rtb.ClientSize.Width)
    {
        rtb.ReadOnly = true;
    }


Use TextRenderer.MeasureText or Graphics.MeasureString

A few suggestions and a modified custom Control you can test.
The Location and Size Properties need to be specified in the designated Container, when the Control is created. The Control itself is not concerned with the layout inside its Parent.
private void InitializeForm()
{
    var customBox = new CustomTextBox() {
        Font = new Font("Segoe UI", 20f, FontStyle.Regular, GraphicsUnit.Point);
        Location = new Point(54, 50);
        Size = new Size(600, 120);
    }
    Controls.Add(customBox)
}

Based on the current scenario, I'd suggest:

Prevent the User from pasting text inside this Control. You could truncate the text after a paste operation, but given the limited text it's meant to contain, this allows to reduce the number of tests / checks you have to do
Prevent the Control from scrolling to the last line of text. TextBoxBase Controls are configured by default to auto-scroll to the bottom, to show the next blank line while adding new text. You probably don't want that, so ES_AUTOVSCROLL and ES_AUTOHSCROLL are removed from the Control's Styles in CreateParams.
To limit the text that a User can enter, you have some options, as tracking the logical position of the last character, to check whether it still falls within the bounds of the ClientRectangle. Here, I'm simply measuring the text when a Key is pressed, to see what it's going to be after a new char is entered, or a line feed is generated, and suppress the Key if the new content causes the text to overflow.


public class CustomRichTextBox : RichTextBox {
    const int ES_AUTOVSCROLL = 0x0040;
    const int ES_AUTOHSCROLL = 0x0080;

    TextFormatFlags flags = TextFormatFlags.WordBreak | 
                            TextFormatFlags.TextBoxControl;

    public CustomRichTextBox() {
        BorderStyle = BorderStyle.None;
        ScrollBars = RichTextBoxScrollBars.None;
        ForeColor = Color.Black;
        BackColor = Color.Yellow;
    }

    protected override CreateParams CreateParams {
        get { 
            var cp = base.CreateParams;
            // Disable auto-scroll to last insert line
            cp.Style &= ~(ES_AUTOVSCROLL | ES_AUTOHSCROLL);
            return cp;
        }
    }

    protected override bool ProcessCmdKey(ref Message m, Keys keyData) {
        if (keyData == (Keys)Shortcut.CtrlV || keyData == (Keys)Shortcut.ShiftIns) {
            return true;  // Suppress CTRL+V & SHIFT+INS
        }
        return base.ProcessCmdKey(ref m, keyData);
    }

    protected override void OnKeyDown(KeyEventArgs e) {
        if (!IsInputKey(e.KeyData) && e.KeyCode != Keys.Delete) {
            var newText = new StringBuilder(Text, TextLength + 2)
                .Insert(SelectionStart, e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter ? "\nM" : (char)e.KeyCode);

            var textHeight = TextRenderer.MeasureText(newText.ToString(), Font, ClientSize, flags).Height;

            if (textHeight > (ClientSize.Height + 1)) { // (0 to n-1) + 1
                e.SuppressKeyPress = true;
            }
        }
        base.OnKeyDown(e);
    }
}

